# Do Vacuum Constriction Devices (penis pumps) work 50-80% of the time for erectile dysfunction?

Tags: physiology, sexuality, erectile-dysfunction

The authoritative [WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/) site has an article [*Erectile Dysfunction: Vacuum Constriction Devices*](http://www.webmd.com/erectile-dysfunction/guide/vacuum-constriction-devices#2):

> A vacuum constriction device (VCD) is an external pump with a band on it that a man with erectile dysfunction can use to get and maintain an erection.

[...]

> Studies suggest that about 50%-80% of men are satisfied with the
>   results of VCDs. As with any other method of treatment for erectile
>   dysfunction (ED), satisfaction rates may decrease with time.

The article doesn't cite any study or reference. Is the 50-80% statistic accurate?

Comment: Worth noting: "satisfied with results" is not necessarily "results were statistically meaningfully different from placebo" (due to sensitivity of the topic I'll refrain from explaining plausible mechanisms)

Comment: @user5341, would you like to elaborate on your comment and make it into an answer?